# Distance between Skew lines

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d

The following is the derivation of the distance between 2 skew lines in vector form,
We shall consider two skew lines, say l1 and l­2 and we are to calculate the distance between them. The equations of the lines are:
$\vec{r}_1 = \vec{a}_1 + t.\vec{b}_1$
$\vec{r}_2 = \vec{a}_2 + t.\vec{b}_2$
P =$\vec{a}_1$is a point on line l1 and Q =$\vec{a}_2$ is a point on line l1. The vectro from P to Q will be $\vec{a}_2$ -$\vec{a}_1$. The unit vector normal to both the lines is given by, $(\vec{b}_1 \times \vec{b}_2) / | \vec{b}_1 \times \vec{b}_2 |$. Then, the shortest distance between the two skew lines will be the projection of PQ on the normal, which is given by $d = | (\vec{a}_2 – \vec{a}_1) .  (\vec{b}_1 \times \vec{b}_2) | / | \vec{b}_1 \times \vec{b}_2|$.

Now in this derivation I dont understand whhy would the distance between the two lines have the same magnitude as the projection of PQ, it will have the same direction i understand that but why would it have the same magnitude can someone explain, shouldnt the distance between them be $\lambda$PQ where $\lambda$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Since you agree that the distance between the two skew lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ is measured along their common normal, then isn't *the projection of PQ on this normal* exactly this required distance?

(To be clear, the endpoints of this projection are the intersections of this normal with $l_1$ and $l_2,$ respectively.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $AB$ be the distance between the two lines ($A\in l_1$ and $B\in l_2$). Then line $AB$ is perpendicular to both $l_1$ and $l_2$. It follows that the projection of $P$ on $AB$ is $A$ and the projection of $Q$ on $AB$ is $B$.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to prove this mathematically?

Comment: @BlackThunder Are you suggesting Geometry is not a part of Mathematics?

Comment: @BlackThunder: One can prove this by parametrising the lines as $\ell_1 = A + \lambda_1(P - A)$ and $\ell_2 = B + \lambda_2(Q - B)$, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.  The distance between points $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is an everywhere continuous differentiable function, and being nonnegative, it reaches an extremum whenever its square reaches an extremum (the squared distance is easier, mathematically).  Per Fermat's theorem (interior extremum theorem), extrema occur where the derivative is zero. [...]

Comment: [...] If you take the partial derivative of the distance squared with respect to $\lambda_1$ equal to zero, and the partial derivative of the distance squared with respect to $\lambda_2$ equal to zero, you'll have a system of two equations in two unknowns.  Examining the system, you'll see that there is only one solution where both partial derivatives are zero (but only when the lines are not parallel – you'll have a vector cross product as a divisor): where the line through the two points denoted by $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is perpendicular to both $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$.

Comment: @Glärbo In my opinion it is preferable to define the distance between two lines in purely geometrical terms, as a segment which is perpendicular to both lines. Of course one must then prove such a segment exists and has a single measure. And one can also easily show (geometrically) that such a segment is the minimal distance between two points on the lines.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: Yes, I do agree: the geometric definition (and solutions derived directly from that) are superior – if not for any other reason, because they're less work! :-)  The reason I commented, was just to show that if one does not grasp the problem geometrically, one can use basic vector algebra and simple calculus to *prove* that the geometric solution is correct.  Not because there is any doubt! Just to help a learner to see things from multiple perspectives, so they can integrate and use what they learn, not just take things axiomatically.